# Decreasing sequence on a measure space

Tags: measure-theory

I have the following problem:

Let $\mu$ be a measure on the measure space $(X,\mathbf{A})$. Let $\{A_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a decreasing sequence in $\mathbf{A}$ so that $A_{n} \in \mathbf{A}$ for all $n\geq1$ and $A_{1} \supseteq A_{2} \supseteq A_{3}...,$

Let $A = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$

(a) Assume that $\mu(A_{n})\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq 1$. Is it true that $\mu(A)=0$. (Provide a proof or counter example.)

I don't know how to approach such a problem and I have more of them so I would be really thankful for a general way to solve these types of problems.

Anyone with some knowledge of this?

Comment: $\mu(A) \leq \mu(A_n) \leq \frac 1 n$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

More generally we have a theorem that states the following:

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra and let $\mu:\mathcal{A} \to [0,\infty]$ be a set function for which $\mu(\emptyset)=0$. If we have a decreasing sequence of sets $A_n\subseteq A_{n-1}$ in $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then:

$$\mu\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(A_n)$$
We say that the measure(or set function more generally) is continuous from above in the set $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$. If you are not familiar with algebras or more general measure theory then just know that every $\sigma$-algebra is an algebra and since it is given that $\mu$ is a measure it will satisfy the conditions of this theorem.

Comment: Thanks, I do have that Theorem in my book. So would I be able to write that: $\mu(A)=\mu(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n})= \lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(A_{n}) \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0 $ ?

Comment: @Eod Enaj That is correct. And the lower bound of $\mu(\boldsymbol{A})$ is obviously $0$ because $\mu$ is a measure.

Comment: Thx that is very helpful. Just one more example if you have the time:
Now I have that $\mu(A_{n}) \geq 1$ and I want to investigate if that means that $\mu(A) \geq 1$. 
It get that $\mu(A)=\mu(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n})= \lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(A_{n}) \geq \lim_{n \to \infty}1 = 1 $.
But does this mean that one can conclude that $\mu(A) \geq 1$ is in fact true cause the sequence is decreasing or it is false cause the limit is just 1?

Comment: Yes you would get the bound $\mu(A) \geq 1$ as long as you have that $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense!

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**

$\mu(A) \leq \mu(A_n)$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}.$